# Counter on Button “Save”

Tags: swift, button, save, counter, payment

Hello everyone i need help guys)... i wanna make a button "snapShotButton" with counter when i press on button 3 times, i want to make a alert where write"you need to pay for use this app". And when i press "ok" he will pay with MKStoreKit... I have MKStoreKit and my app is Video Editor... Thanks for help best regards!!

```html
func addButtons() {

let snapShotButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        snapShotButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "snapShot").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        snapShotButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bottomTabBar.addSubview(snapShotButton)
        snapShotButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomTabBar.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        snapShotButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomTabBar.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        snapShotButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true
        snapShotButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true
        snapShotButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(snapShotButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        snapShotButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(counterAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

func counterAction(sender:UIButton){
        
        counter -= 1
        print(counter)
        
        if counter == 0 {
        MKStoreKit.shared().initiatePaymentRequestForProduct(withIdentifier: "com.steinlogic.iapdemo.quarterly")
        }
    }
    
    
    func snapShotButtonTapped() {
        pauseVideo()
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: self.videoURL)
        }) { saved, error in
            if saved {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { _ in
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
            else {
                self.alertErrors()
            }
        }
        //alertNotAvailable()
    }
```

Comment: What is not happening with this code?

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Your code looks correct for me? Any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save the counter's value in `UserDefaults` and retreive it after every app start. After the payment has happened, you can skip the counter decrementation alltogether.